# reading , zoom and move images like remote sensing image (e.g jpg,tiff,img) by managed DX

Tags: xna, directx, zooming, tiff, gdal

excuse me,my english is poor however i would try to describe my questions clearly.
first i want to operate (read,zoom,move,zoom with rectangle) some image whose format like jpg,tiff and img .
i have try to do this by gdal,using rasterio to zoom and move ,but the result is quite strange.it's slow than i do it with gdi+.i have asked other people,however ,the answer may be rasterio read image direct from hard disk, but gdi+ do things in ram. and maybe the images i operated are small images ,small than 4000*3000.
so now i operate images in gdi+.but i think if i can do same things in directx?
i mean i use directx instead gdi+.because i think it will be more fast.
and because i can only use c#,so i think there are some people could give me some suggestion with managed dx or xna
thx~~~

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you are trying to build a simple image viewer.
If so you can easily do it with XNA and it will work very fast.

All you need to do is to load the image and display it to the screen, and the pan and zoom are also very simple.

Read this tutorial : 
http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/spritebatch-basics

Comment: THX very much~I learn a lot from the tutorial~yeah,but i still don't know how to pan and zoom,the tutorial don't mention about that~eh,can i ask a question,how about using wpf rather than winform to do it,i think it will be fast~ at last,what i want to do is not display the resmote sensing image,what i want to do is resmote sensing image processing~~

Answer (score 0):

There is already a fast image viewer called TuiView that is simple to install and use.

Documentation is here: http://tuiview.org